# Why am I getting an error "TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)"

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

***I'm trying to make a script that takes information and stores it in a file for a different program***

My code is this,

```
import os

currentinfo = input("Enter username: ")

os.system('echo', "Username:", currentinfo, ">> info.txt")
```

The error I'm getting is,

```
os.system('echo', "Username:", currentinfo)
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

How do I fix this?

**I'm new to python, so bear with me.**

Comment: Error is pretty straight forward. You can only provide one argument.
Change your code to ```os.system('echo Username: {}".format(currentinfo))```

Comment: that `>>` stuff isn't going to work either... you could put the `>> info.txt"` inside the argument to system(), but you should really look into how to write files using open() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Python sees `'echo'`, `"Username:"`, `currentinfo`, and `">> info.txt"` as different arguments instead of a concatenated string like you were hoping for. Variables passed to a function separated by commas are interpreted as arguments.

To fix this, either concatenate your string with the `+` operator or use a formated string(a much cleaner option).

### Using the `+` operator:

```
os.system('echo Username: ' + currentinfo + ' >> info.txt')
```

### Using a formatted string:

```
os.system(f'echo Username: {currentinfo} >> info.txt')
```

or:

```
os.system('echo Username: {} >> info.txt'.format(currentinfo))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straightforward - you are invoking the `system` method of the `os` package with 3 arguments. [Checking the api](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) confirms this takes 1 argument, not 3. So, one way to solve this would be to combine all your terms into 1 string argument. You probably also need quotes around what you are passing to `echo`:

```
os.system(f'echo "Username: {currentinfo}" >> info.txt')
```

As at least 1 comment suggested, it would be more pythonic to use code to write to a file, rather than relying on a system call. As you are using `>>` I'll assume you want to append to the file, rather than overwriting it if it already exists:

```
currentinfo = input("Enter username: ")
text_to_write = f'Username: {currentinfo}'
with open('info.txt', 'a') as outfile:  # the 'a' sets append mode
    outfile.write(text_to_write)        # <-- optionally add a \n if you want a newline
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Comment: The text on the file outputs as "Username:", and then the directory to where the python file is

Comment: I ran the code exactly as in my response, and it generated a text file `info.txt` with `Username: My User Name` in it. Are you getting the current directory, or running other code?

Comment: I'm only running the code that I stated in my OP.

Its "Username: " then the directory to the file, then "Username: test123"

Comment: There is no mention of directories in your post. What am I missing? If you are using anything not in your post, please add it so we can see.

Comment: I mean the directory to the python file I'm running


Like /users/username/Desktop/Applications/Utilities/Terminal

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. Where are you using the directory to your python script? It is not in your code.

Comment: That's the whole point, When I ran your code, it showed the directory, And I don't know why